# How to build a stage wise prediction in a binary classification problem

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset with 500K records with 12 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. The dependent variable is binary(0(No) and 1(Yes)).
I am trying to build an algorithm that gives me a classification probability at various stages.
I need to perform some actions when a certain data point is tending towards a Yes.
for example, at 30% perform some action. at 50% perform some action and 80% perform another action. and 90% kill the activity.
I know it a kind of an early detection system but I need to know the probabilities as well.
I am thinking to build a classification algorithm using 4 variables, 6 variables, 8 variables, and then 11 variables.
I feel there is a better way to do it. Please let me know what you people think.

Comment: My understanding here is to first train your network based on any probabilistic model like Logistic, Neural net etc and achieve the desired accuracy. Once done , then use the model raw output i.e sigmoid probabilities to perform actions.

Comment: Thanks, Aditya. I already did that and a good accuracy level. The way I want to build it is when my model reads say 4 features, it should give me some probabilities. When I introduce 3 more features, the probabilities should change.